# form checkbox to email

Tags: php, email, checkbox

I am new to development and have been working hours to try to figure out how to get the checkbox results to my email.  I have read and tried multiple options that I have found but none are working.  Please let me know what I am doing wrong!

HTML

```
 <form id="contactForm" action="form_to_email.php" method="post" >

<fieldset class="contact">

    <label class="labelOne" for="name">Name <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="name"size="30" required />


     <label for="email">Email <span>*</span></label>
     <input type="text" name="email" size="30" required/>

     <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" 
              type= "text"minlength="2"></textarea>

    <label for="phone">Cell Phone</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" size="15" />

 </fieldset>

<fieldset class="checkboxes">
    <p>I am interested in ...</p>
           <label for="runstrong"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" 
          name="interest[]" value="runstrong">runstrong</label>

         <label for="bestrong"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" 
          name="interest[]" value="bestrong">be strong</label>

         <label for="runstrong"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" 
         name="interest[]" value="subscribe">receiving your newsletter</label>

        <label for="personal training"><input class="checkbox" 
        type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="personal training">
        personal training</label>
 </fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" />

    <input class="btn" type="reset" value="Clear Form" name="reset" />
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "myemail@verizon.net";

 /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "First and Last Name");
$email = check_input($_POST['email']);
$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Write your message");
$phone = check_input($_POST['phone']);

 $interest = isset($_POST['interest'])
? implode(',',$_POST['interest'])
:'intersted in';


/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
 {
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
   $message = "
   Name: $name
   E-mail: $email
   Cell phone :$phone
   Message:$message
   Interest:$interest 
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

 /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location:thank_you.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
 $data = trim($data);
 $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
 if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
 {
    show_error($problem);
  }
     return $data;
  }

     function show_error($myError)
  {
   ?>
   <html>
        <body>

     <p>Please correct the following error:</p>
      <strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
      <p>Please hit the back button and try again</p>

    </body>
     </html>
    <?php
  exit();
      }
```

Comment: Your problem lies within the naming of the inputs... they are all named "interest[]", you should find a way to figure out which interests are actually inside of that array.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?